Did gcc and clang accidentally drop C99 sequence point conformance?
Background:
C99 6.5 §2 said:

Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored.

Where "the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored" would equal what C11 calls value computation (new formal term in C11).
The corresponding text in C11 6.5 §2:

If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined if such an unsequenced side effect occurs in any of the orderings.

When dissecting this closer as done in this question, the last sentence in particular marks a difference in behavior between C99 and C11. In code such as this
#define get_next() (0,array[i++])
...
get_next() + get_next()

it does not modify the stored value more than once between the previous and next sequence point (C99). However in C11, in the expanded sub-expressions (0,array[i++]) +  (0,array[i++]), the two i++ are unsequenced in relation to each other, despite the sequence points. Essentially C11 allows the compiler to evaluate the program in this order:
0
0
array[i++]
array[i++]
+

So that would mean undefined behavior. Whereas C99 doesn't care, the above is merely unspecified behavior there, C99 6.5 §3:

...the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified.


My question:
Did gcc and clang forget all about C99 (and earlier) compliance when implementing C11 support? Minimal example:
int i;
int array[10];

#define get_next() (0,array[i++])

int main (void)
{
  get_next() + get_next();
}

clang 18.1.0 -std=c99 -pedantic:

multiple unsequenced modifications to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]

What is "unsequenced"? There is no such term in C99 and why should I care about C11 and beyond issues in conforming C99 code?
gcc 14.1 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall:

operation on 'i' may be undefined

Undefined according to whom? Not according to C99 6.5 §2.
The diagnostic messages in each compiler appear to be incorrect. I don't know if the compilers also generate code accordingly and treat this as UB, but if they do that might be yet another problem.

The behavior is undefined in C 1999 because (A, B) + (C, D) may be evaluated as A C X Y B D +, where X is the sequence point required in (A, B) and Y is the sequence point of (C, D). Then the i++ in C and the i++ in D modifyi twice between sequence points (between Y and the end of the full expression).

@EricPostpischil Is that kind of re-ordering or "parallel evaluation" really permitted though? C11 allows it as per sequenced before/sequenced after/indeterminately sequenced. Supposedly this was the reason why these terms were added in C11 5.1.2.3 and the rationale was to introduce out-of-order evaluation.

@EricPostpischil Specifically C11 added "The presence of a sequence point between the evaluation of expressions A and B implies that every value computation and side effect associated with A is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with B." This appears to be the very rule your example refers to.

Re “Is that kind of re-ordering or "parallel evaluation" really permitted though?”: C has always allowed implementations to evaluate subexpressions in arbitrary orders, except as otherwise stated, including intermingling parts of subexpressions. A*B+C*D could always be evaluated in the order A C B * D * +, and others, and, further, subparts of eqch of those could be reordered. Changing * to , introduces a requirement for a sequence point between A and B, with A first, and another between C and D but does not introduce any requirements between A and C or  between B and D…

… If the implementation did choose A X B C Y D +, then there would be a sequence point (Y) between B and D, so every side effect of B would be completed before D, but it is not required to choose that order.

@EricPostpischil Fair enough but as mentioned in the question that is explicitly unspecified behavior as per C99 6.5 §3. It is not obvious to me that it is also undefined behavior. The relevant part stating that it is UB is 6.5 no matter version of the standard. But C99 did not have the text "If there are multiple allowable orderings of the subexpressions of an expression, the behavior is undefined". It does have the text "the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the order in which side effects take place are both unspecified"

So C 2011 added text explicitly covering multiple allowed orderings. This likely corrected an oversight in C 1999. Without explicit text in C 1999, its general rule applies: Undefined behavior is “indicated” by the lack of definition. Since nothing defined what happens if there is undefined behavior in one allowable ordering but not others, the standard does not define what happens.

@EricPostpischil Just FYI, the 20 valid evaluation orders of (A, B) + (C, D) are: AXBCYD+, AXCBYD+, AXCYBD+, AXCYDB+, ACXBYD+, ACXYBD+, ACXYDB+, ACYXBD+, ACYXDB+, ACYDXB+, CAXBYD+, CAXYBD+, CAXYDB+, CAYXBD+, CAYXDB+, CAYDXB+, CYAXBD+, CYAXDB+, CYADXB+, CYDAXB+ (where X is the sequence point between A and B, and Y is the sequence point between C and D).
